# run cronjob button is not visible in backoffice-SAP Hyrbis 1905?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

We did the Hybris upgrade from 6.7 to 1905. Storefront is working fine. But while trying to run the cronjobs from backoffice. Its not showing the **cronjob run button**.

**Solr indexing button** also not visible in backoffice. Please let me know if I miss anything.

[image: Cronjob run button missing]

[image: Solr Indexing button missing]

Can you please help me on this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is the cronjob active?

Comment: Yes, Even solr indexing button also not visible

Comment: Hi Arvind, I have updated the query with screenshots. Please click on "Cronjob run button missing" and "Solr indexing button missing" links to seet the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user with which you log into Backoffice is a member of `backoficeadmingroup` (or `admingroup`). I assume the `F4 - Reset Everything - F4` sequence was run as well.

Comment: Hi Glenn,
I have logged in with the user is member of admingroup. I have tried with the  F4-Reset Everything. But its not working.........

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
local.properties -> tomcat.generaloptions=-Djava.io.tmpdir={HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}
```

This fixed the cron job icon issue.